# Validation error showing up after submit in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have a form that allows users to post comments in my Angular 5 application.

I'm trying to clear the form after the comment is posted, but getting a validation error, as if the form is being submitted twice.

```js
export class CommentCreateComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() newComment = new EventEmitter<Comment>();

  comment: Comment = {
    content: '',
    author: '',
  };

  constructor(
    private commentService: CommentService) { }

  onSubmit() {

    var self = this;
    this.commentService.createComment(this.comment)
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          this.newComment.emit(result as Comment);
          // The next line causes me problems.
          // this.requestComment.content = '';
        },
        error => {
        });
  }
}
```

And the html:

```html
<form name="form" 
      (ngSubmit)="createComment.form.valid && onSubmit()" 
      #createRequestComment="ngForm" 
      novalidate>
  <textarea name="content" 
            minlength="2" 
            required 
            maxlength="300"  
            id="content" 
            #content="ngModel" 
            [(ngModel)]="comment.content" ></textarea>
  <div *ngIf="content.invalid && createRequestComment.submitted" 
       class="text-danger">
    Comment is required and must be between 2 and 300 characters long.
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="button">Post Comment</button>

</form>
```

Everything works well with the above, but the problem is that once a user posts a comment, the text box still has their old text in it.

If I uncomment this line:

```
this.requestComment.content = '';
```

Then the comment gets posted, the text box is cleared, but my validation error shows up.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985754/965834. Looks like the same question to me.

Comment: what is `createComment`?  `createRequestComment` is template ref, you need to pass it to your Component ts file  `onSubmit(createRequestComment)`

Comment: Edit to my comment earlier: seems like `resetForm` is the way to go, despite that answer mentioning `reset`. See @KimKern's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the reference of your form to your `onSubmit`.

```html
<form name="form" 
      (ngSubmit)="createComment.form.valid && onSubmit(createRequestComment)" 
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      #createRequestComment="ngForm" 
      novalidate>
```

In your `onSubmit`, call `form.resetForm()` to completely reset your form instead of `this.requestComment.content = ''`.

```js
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  ...
  form.resetForm();
  ...
}
```