# Best way to reset a ngForm in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm working with an ngForm that is inside of a sidebar that toggles. That sidebar was the textfields to enter the andress, payment info etc. Essentially I want to reset the form and I know I can either Destroy the component that has the form or just reset the form (like my example below). Which one is better to use and why?

```
<form #heroForm="ngForm">
    ...
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="newHero(); heroForm.reset()">New Hero</button>
</form>
```

I took a look to this queston [Cleanest way to reset forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500102/cleanest-way-to-reset-forms) but it didn't answer mine.

Comment: `I took a look to this queston Cleanest way to reset forms but it didn't answer mine.` <= why not?

Comment: @Igor because it seems like the example is just a simple form. Right here I'm dealing with payment process (waiting for the response and all that) the customer can toggle the component that contains the form too and on toggle it should reset, but only when a payment is completed or not happening. You can destroy or reset the form if the the payment is being proecessed

Comment: The Angular [NgForm object comes with a reset method](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#resetform)

Comment: Correct, but idk if destroying the component was better practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Patricio Vargas..  try to assign `null` to your form fields in  `newHero()` after your logic is completed.If you are using a model to your `heroForm` then code will be

```
    public hero= new Hero();

    newHero() {
     //do your logic here after that
     this.hero.name= '';
     this.hero.age= '';
     this.hero.active = null;
    }
```

In latest angular, Model based Forms are not working with  `formsName.reset()`.So this will solve your issue .. otherwise have a look here https://angular.io/guide/forms#submit-the-form-with-ngsubmit