# Form validation errors persist through routing

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms

**In my application I have the following problem:**

Users can display multiple `guests` through a `GuestManager` component that presents a list of `guests`. If a user clicks one guest, the detail view is displayed (`CustomerEditSingleGuestComponent` component) - pretty much a regular master/detail view.

The routing of the detail component looks like this:

```
[...]
{
  path: ':guestId',
  component: CustomerEditSingleGuestComponent,
  canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard],
},
[...]
```

So far so good. The `CustomerEditSingleGuestComponent` contains a form with validation, which works fine when editing a guest for the first time (relative to SPA lifetime). If a user switches to another guest that is not yet filled in, all form inputs display their validation errors immediately instead of waiting for the user's input.

This does not conform to my validation strategy, as we intend to only present error messages after a `form input` has been touched (works fine for the first guest edit process). It seems rather confusing for a user if all required fields are marked red when they open the second / following `guest data forms`.

**My assumption here is**, that Angular reuses the component when switching from `Guest A` to `Guest B` as only a route param changes, and the same component should be displayed. Apparently the `form` is persisted as well, and I was not able to reset the form (the values are reset, but the validation errors are still display immediately) - I tried accessing the form via ViewChild and use `reset()`, `resetForm()`, `markAsPristine()` and `markAsUntouched()` in various combinations, and it seems I am not the only one:

[Cleanest way to reset forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500102/cleanest-way-to-reset-forms)

I have thought about nasty workarounds (routing to parent and then to the next `guestId`, using `*ngIf` and `setTimeout` to remove the form form DOM and force a reload). Nevertheless I am still hopeful that there is a decent and clean solution for the problem?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, If components displayed in Tabs Components, ngInit will be called only once, as it will cache the component creation stuff for performance reasons. Using Router Change subscribe method will be called every time.

We need to manually reset the re-active form, good place is ngOnDestroy component life cycle method.

Here is the code

```
static resetForm(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    let control: AbstractControl = null;
    formGroup.reset();
    formGroup.markAsUntouched();
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach((name) => {
      control = formGroup.controls[name];
      control.setErrors(null);
    });
  }
```