# How to clear an Angular reactive form input values

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a simple reactive form set up like this

```
constructor(private scheduleService: ScheduleService, fb: FormBuilder) {
this.searchForm = fb.group({
  from: ["", Validators.required],
  to: ["", Validators.required],
  date: ["", Validators.required]
});
}
```

I want to clear the form fields by click on a button that calls the clear function. My clear function currently doesn't work and looks like this

```
clear() {
console.log("Reset all search form fields to null.");

this.searchForm.from = "";
this.searchForm.to = "";
this.searchForm.date = "";
}
```

What is the right way to clear form input fields when working with angular reactive forms? How can I achieve this by using a single statement to reset all form fields instead of individual fields?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cleanest way to reset forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500102/cleanest-way-to-reset-forms)

Comment: @ConnorsFan thanks for your comment. Found the solution there.

Answer (score 12):

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
      from: ['', Validators.required],
      to: ['', Validators.required],
      date: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

reset complete form

```
  resetForm() {
    this.searchForm.reset();
  }
```

reset individual field

```
  resetFrom() {
    this.searchForm.get('from').reset();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

"data" will be your form data

```
   searchForm!: FormGroup;

   this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [''],
      address: ['']
    });

     clearForm() {
        try{
          let data={
               name:'',
               address:''
              }
           this.searchForm.reset(data);
         }
        catch(ex){
          console.log(ex)
         }
    
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

for reset one input

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
      from: ['', Validators.required],
      to: ['', Validators.required],
      date: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

convenience getter for easy access to form fields

```
  get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }
```

reset one field exmple (from )

```
this.f.from.reset();
```

Comment: This is absolutely wrong, first, it doesn't solve the issue, then even if it does, this is going to reset the whole form, whereas you said it'll reset one field!