# Which is a best practice to use `reset()` and `resetForm()` methods in angular and why?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am using Template driven form in my application.
When i'am submitting the form then that time i have use `reset` method.
I have found another `formReset()` method, i have check both `method` they work as same
For Angular best practice which `method` is useful to use? and how?

Comment: `reset` is used on your HTML to reset the form, `resetForm` is an Angular function tied to a form instance, that orks both for template driven and reactive forms. Both work well, but I woulg use reset for template driven, and reset form for reactive, because one is correlated to the HTML while the other one isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a Model driven form to reset the form we just need to call the function reset() on our model for to resets all the input fields to go back to their initial state.

similarly To reset form in template driven form, NgForm has resetForm() method to reset the form.

I hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to use the one that comes with Form, i.e. `reset()`. The method `reset()` of form resets the states of the form controls so any validation styling and errors reset also to the original pristine condition.

You can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985754/11016183) of a similar question

Answer (score 1):

**Reset**
Resets the form control, marking it `pristine` and `untouched`, and setting
the value to null.

**ResetForm**

```
 Resets the form value and resets its submitted status.
```

Answer (score 0):

Both work to **reset** the form. However, **reset()** could sometime give you error when you have used **<mat-error>** to display errors for unfilled input fields, but **resetForm()** would not give you such errors.