# make a valid form Angular 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I need reset my form, when using this method

```js
 public static resetDescriptionFields(i: any, component: any) {
            var formItens = component.form.get('itens') as FormArray;
            var itemDescription = formItens.controls[i].get('description');
            itemDescription.get('descriptionProduct').reset();
            itemDescription.get('destination').reset();
            formItens.updateValueAndValidity();
        }
```

Who turn form valid ?

Comment: I hope this will help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500102/cleanest-way-to-reset-forms

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz for the same?

Comment: Maybe I can not, it's a form that has a lot of module, and a small part that depends on other big ones. I would like this method to redo form and become invalid to valid

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Reactive form you can reset your form to valid state like this

Update: You may also need to store default value into variable

```
public yourForm: FormGroup;

let yourDefaultState = {} // some object;
```

Then in your reset form value

```
this.yourForm.reset(this.yourDefaultState);
this.yourForm.markAsPristine();
this.yourForm.markAsUntouched();
```

Comment: This property continued invalid itemDescription.get('descriptionProduct').reset();

Comment: "some object". 
Why do I want to spend some value or seed on this empty object?